# Missing rows in influxdb database

Tags: python, database, influxdb

I have a python code that pipes `ps aux` output from terminal and sends it to InfluxDB.

```
def main(host='localhost', port=8086):
    user = '----'
    password = '----'
    dbname = '----'
    protocol = 'line'
    client = DataFrameClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)
    a = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'aux'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")
    # a = a.translate(None, '%')
    pyperclip.copy(a)
    df = pd.read_clipboard(index_col=False)
    df = df[["USER", "%CPU", "%MEM", "START"]]
    # df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
    ind = pd.DatetimeIndex(data=df["START"])
    df.set_index(ind, inplace=True)
    print(df)
    client.create_database(dbname)
    client.write_points(df, dbname, protocol=protocol)
```

I get a table with 400+ rows.

When I open InfluxDB and select everything from the database it only reads 22 rows.

```
time            %CPU    %MEM    START   USER
----            ----    ----    -----   ----
1570543920000000000 0   0   14:12   ani
1570543980000000000 0   0.3 14:13   root
1570544040000000000 0   0.4 14:14   ani
1570544100000000000 0   0   14:15   ani
1570544160000000000 0.1 1.1 14:16   ani
1570544520000000000 0   0   14:22   ani
1570544700000000000 0.1 0.6 14:25   grafana
1570545060000000000 0   0   14:31   ani
1570545240000000000 0   0.1 14:34   ani
1570545300000000000 0   0   14:35   ani
1570545780000000000 0   0   14:43   root
1570545960000000000 0   0   14:46   root
1570547460000000000 0   0   15:11   root
1570547580000000000 0   0   15:13   ani
1570548240000000000 0   0   15:24   root
1570548660000000000 0.2 0.4 15:31   influxdb
1570549560000000000 0   0   15:46   root
1570549740000000000 0   0   15:49   root
1570549800000000000 0   0.6 15:50   ani
1570550040000000000 0   0   15:54   ani
1570550100000000000 0   0   15:55   root
1570550160000000000 0   0   15:56   ani
```

Where is the rest of the data?

Comment: Write into a file first and check are you really sending 400 rows to Influxdb.

Comment: I did that. I got csv with 400+ rows. 
Today I discovered that influx somehow ignores the duplicate rows (with at lease one same tag?). Any idea how can I fix that?

Comment: Every point(record) should have a unique timestamp, along with tags. If they all same InfluxDb will update the existing record.